# Set resolution for camera in IOS for AI

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturedevice

I am working on a project where I start the camera and then capture images live to image processing. This project has guided me [TensorFlow - Image Classification](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/ios/ImageClassification/Camera%20Feed/CameraFeedManager.swift). One thing I can't figure out despite looking in the documentation and searching on Google is how to set the resolution of the camera.

Is it possible to either get it, or to set it programmatically? Here is the code where I create the camera:

```
 private func addVideoDeviceInput() -> Bool {
        
        /**Tries to get the default back camera.
         */
        guard let camera  = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back) else {
            return false
        }
        do {
            let videoDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera)
            if session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput) {
                session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
                return true
            }
            else {
                return false
            }
        }
        catch {
            fatalError("Cannot create video device input")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, check out [`sessionPreset`.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession/1389696-sessionpreset)

```
session.sessionPreset = .photo /// here!
if session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput) {
    session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
    return true
}
```

Comment: Aha, I found something called AVCaptureSessionPreset, but it did not exist when I tried it in XCode. This is maybe the new version. Thanks alot!

Comment: @El_Loco try `AVCaptureSession.Preset`